# Bar plot in my multipage dash app (python) is not being displayed. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

Bar plot in my multipage dash app (python) is not being displayed. What am I doing wrong?

```
from dash import html
import plotly.express as px
from data import Rejects1
from navbar import create_navbar

df = Rejects1.dfrj

nav = create_navbar()

header = px.bar(df, x='date', y='amount', color='reject_type', height=400, width=1400)


def create_rejects1():
    layout = html.Div([
        nav,
        header,
    ]),
    return layout
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't duplicate your code, but there are alternatives for displaying at:
https://plotly.com/python/renderers/